# How do I get a parameter's value from a CGI Perl app?

Tags: html, perl, cgi, param

I am trying to get value from a form. My HTML is as below:

```
<select name="new_id" ><option value="464">464</option></select>
```

I am trying to get the value using:

```
my $clientId2 = param('new_id');
```

But I am getting $clientId2 as empty. Its working for all other tag except this one.

Comment: Are you using `use strict; use warnings;`? If not, add them and see what happens. And also add the code where you check what value is in your variable, and copy/paste the code, don't write it.

Comment: Typically, you'd use list context for multi-valued elements, like checkboxes; see what happens if you explicitly use the `checked` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Disabled controls aren't sent when a form is submitted.

Comment: I did removed the disabled and same problem.